# Taking screenshots from part of the web page with python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, screenshot

I have been able to catch screenshots as pngs of some elements such the one with following code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from os.path import expanduser
from time import sleep

# Define url and driver
url = 'https://www.formula1.com/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')

# Go to url, scroll down to right point on page and find correct element
driver.get(url)
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, 4100)')
sleep(4) #  Wait a little for page to load
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('race-list')
location = element.location
size = element.size
png = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
driver.quit()

# Store image as bytes, crop it and save to desktop
im = Image.open(BytesIO(png))
im = im.crop((200, 150, 700, 725))
path  = expanduser('~/Desktop/')
im.save(path + 'F1-info.png')
```

This outputs to:

[image]

Which is what I want but not exactly how I want. I needed to manually input some scrolling down and as I couldn't get the element I wanted (`class='race step-1 step-2 step-3'`) I had to manually crop the image too.

Any better solutions?

Comment: Did you try to do that in the same way?

Comment: Yeah but that obviously didn't work Changing the class name alone isn't enough. @Andersson

Comment: *"...didn't work..."*. Any exception? Output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is wondering. This is how I managed it in the end. First I found and scrolled to the right part of the page like this

```
element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.race.step-1.step-2.step-3')
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()', element)
browser.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, -80)')
```

and then cropped the image

```
im = im.crop((200, 80, 700, 560))
```